# How can I pass things to a C++20 coroutine co_await await_suspend operator function such as a thread pool reference?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-coroutine

I am trying to work with Coroutines and multithreading together in C++.

In many coroutine examples, they create a new thread in the `await_suspend` of the `co_await` operator for the promise type. I want to submit to a thread pool in this function.

Here I define a `co_await` for `future<int>`.

```
void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
          this->wait();
          handle.resume();
        }
```

I want to change this code to submit a lambda/function pointer to a threadpool. Potentially I can use Alexander Krizhanovsky's ringbuffer to communicate with the threadpool to create a threadpool by myself or use boost's threadpool.

My problem is NOT the thread pool. My problem is that I don't know how to get reference to the threadpool in this `co_await` operator.

How do I pass data from the outside environment where the operator is to this `await_suspend` function? Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
    // how do I get "pool"? from within this function
    auto res = pool.enqueue([](int x) { 
          this->wait();
          handle.resume();
    });
          
}
```

I am not an expert at C++ so I'm not sure how I would get access to `pool` in this operator?

Here's the full code inspired by [this GitHub gist A simple C++ coroutine example](https://gist.github.com/yizhang82/28842f7dbae34b59fcd7b4d74b4a19d4).

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;



template <>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::future<int>> {
  struct promise_type : std::promise<int> {
    future<int> get_return_object() { return this->get_future(); }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_value(int value) { this->set_value(value); }
    void unhandled_exception() {
      this->set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
  };
};

template <>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::future<int>, int> {
  struct promise_type : std::promise<int> {
    future<int> get_return_object() { return this->get_future(); }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_value(int value) { this->set_value(value); }
    void unhandled_exception() {
      this->set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
  };
};

auto operator co_await(std::future<int> future) {
  struct awaiter : std::future<int> {
  
    bool await_ready() { return false; } // suspend always
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
      this->wait();
      handle.resume();
    }
    int await_resume() { return this->get(); }
  };
  return awaiter{std::move(future)};
}

future<int> async_add(int a, int b)
{
    auto fut = std::async([=]() {
        int c = a + b;
        return c;
    });

    return fut;
}

future<int> async_fib(int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
        co_return 1;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    // iterate computing fib(n)
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i)
    {
        int c = co_await async_add(a, b);
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    co_return b;
}

future<int> test_async_fib()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int ret = co_await async_fib(i);
        cout << "async_fib(" << i << ") returns " << ret << endl;
    }
}

int runfib(int arg) {
  auto fut = test_async_fib();
  fut.wait();
  return 0;
}

int run_thread() {
  printf("Running thread");
  return 0;
}
  
int main()
{
    std::list<shared_ptr<std::thread>> threads = { };
      
  
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("Creating thread\n");
      std::shared_ptr<std::thread> thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(runfib, 5);
      
      threads.push_back(thread);
      
    }
    std::list<shared_ptr<std::thread>>::iterator it;
    for (it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); it++) {
      (*it).get()->join();
      printf("Joining thread");
    }
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you need additional context, you'll have to provide it some other way. You could put it in the promise object, or you could put it in an awaiter, or an adapter.

Comment: Can I provide that additional context from the area in the code around the await? I would like to create the thread pool in the main() of my application. Can promise_type receive data from the function statement?

Comment: @SamuelSquire: What operation is the `co_await` expression waiting on? Generally, the way it works is that the thing you're waiting on is what schedules your resumption when it is finished. So that's where the thread pool ought to be, or be accessible from.

Comment: Yes, the promise can [peek at the function parameters in its constructor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5.7).

Comment: Also, FYI: `std::suspend_never final_suspend()` is a bit dangerous, as you can never tell when the `coroutine_handle` is `done` this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a thread pool, and let the coroutine promise schedule work on it.

I have this example around that is not exactly simple but may do the work:

- Make your coroutine return a `task<T>`.

```
task<int> async_add(int a, int b) { ... }
```

- Let the `task` share a `state` with its `coroutine_promise`. The `state`:

  - is implemented as an executable, resuming the coroutine when executed, and
  - holds the result of the operation (e.g. a `std::promise<T>`).

```cpp
template <typename T>
class task<T>::state : public executable {
public:
    void execute() noexcept override {
        handle_.resume();
    }
...
private:
    handle_type handle_;
    std::promise<T> result_;
};
```

- The `coroutine_promise` returns a `task_scheduler` awaiter at `initial_suspend`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class task<T>::coroutine_promise {
public:
    auto initial_suspend() {
        return task_scheduler<task<T>>{};
    }
```

- The `task_scheduler` awaiter schedules the `state`:

```
template <is_task task_t>
struct task_scheduler : public std::suspend_always {
    void await_suspend(task_t::handle_type handle) const noexcept {
        thread_pool::get_instance().schedule(handle.promise().get_state());
    }
};
```

- Wrapping it all up: calls to a coroutine will make a `state` be scheduled on a thread, and, whenever a thread executes that `state`, the coroutine will be resumed. The caller can then wait for the task's result.

```
auto c{ async_add(a,b) };
b = c.get_result();
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/K9s6bTjKb)

Answer (score 1):

That example is from 2018, and was built for the Coroutine TS. So it's missing a lot of stuff from the actual C++20 feature. It also assumes the presence of a lot of things that didn't make it into C++20. The most notable of which being the idea that `std::future` is an awaitable type, and that it has continuation support when coupled with `std::async`.

It's not, and it doesn't. So there's not much you can really learn from this example.

`co_await` is ultimately built on the ability to suspend execution of a function and schedule its resumption after some value has been successfully computed. The actual C++20 `std::future` has exactly *none* of the machinery needed to do that. Nor does `std::asyc` give it the ability to do so.

As such, neither is an appropriate tool for this task.

You need to build your own future type (possibly using `std::promise/future` internally) which has a reference to your thread pool. When you `co_await` on this future, it is that new future which passes off the `coroutine_handle` to the thread pool, doing whatever is needed to ensure that this handle does not get executed until its current set of tasks is done.

Your pool or whatever needs to have a queue of tasks, such that it can insert new ones to be processed after all of the current one, and remove tasks once they've finished (as well as starting the next one). And those operations need to be properly synchronized. This queue needs to be accessible by both the future type and your coroutine's promise type.

When a coroutine ends, the promise needs to tell the queue that its current task is over and to move to the next one, or suspend the thread if there is no next one. And the promise's value needs to be forwarded to the next task. When a coroutine `co_await`s on a future from your system, it needs to add that handle to the queue of tasks to be performed, possibly starting up the thread again.